# CMD Substring Extraction On Output Variable

Tags: batch-file, substring, csv

Looking for guidance on performing substring extraction in a batch script on the variable of a command output. Specifically the command I am using is `powershell (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).version`

I have this variable set up successfully using `for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('"powershell (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).version"') do set OSvar=%%i`

As you can see I am querying OS version, and I have an undisclosed, semi-valid use case for using this specific method to find it. Even if my reasoning behind using the above method to query may be misguided, I still want to learn how to perform substring extraction on this output, for my own edification. Finding a solution is less important than finding a solution in the given context.

Obviously, this will output something to the effect of "6.2.9200", "6.3.9600", or "10.0.XXXXXXX". I want to know how to extract the output before the 2nd decimal, but all of the attempts I've tried after researching are failing, including setting delims and using a second variable set equal to the first with `:~0,3%`. Can the gurus here help a guy out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, split the result by `.`

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2delims=." %%i in ('powershell (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem^).version') do (
    set "OSvar=%%i.%%j"
)
echo %OSvar%
```

or a oneliner from the same code:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2delims=." %%i in ('powershell (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem^).version') do echo %%i.%%j
```

you can use the standard `ver` command as well;

```
@for /f "tokens=1-5,*delims=. " %%i in ('ver') do @set OSvar=%%l.%%m
```

Explanation as requested.
Seeing as we split the string by `.` each token gets to assigned to a metavariable. In other words. Let's assume it is `windows 10.0.18362.959` then `tokens=1,2` will assign `10` to `%%i` and `0` to `%%j`

Comment: This was the solution, thank you. For some reason, ```for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=."``` worked, whereas ```tokens=1,2``` and ```tokens=1,2,3``` didn't work. Can someone explain that to me please?

Comment: It does work with `1,2` 1,2,3*` etc. I updated the answer to prove it `:)` it is the usage of the metavariables. We assign first dotted value to token 1 (Metavariable `%%i`) and second value to token 2 (metavariable `%%j`) Here you cannot use the remainder though as we did not assign a token to it. so `echo %%k` will result in `%%k`. Only if we tell the system that everything after should be assigned to another token, will it be able to use it.

Comment: Of course it is working now with ```tokens=1,2``` even though I swear I have done that with the same syntax before. It goes to show that sometimes you just need to go online and complain about a thing for it to start working, but thank you for your explanations!

Comment: Play around with it, set your own string and see how you can use various parts by using tokens :) Glad you're sorted though.

Comment: If I get the karma to leave meaningful upvotes, I'll upvote your answer again ^^ Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the major and minor numbers, via [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell), then it seems more sensible to return only those, instead of parsing the result afterwards:

```batch-file
For /F %%G In ('^""%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" ^
 -NoProfile -NoLogo -Command "[System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version | " ^
 "ForEach-Object { '{0}.{1}' -F $_.Major,$_.Minor }"^"') Do Set "OSVar=%%G"
```

As a oneliner:

```batch-file
For /F %%G In ('%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoP "[System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version|%%{'{0}.{1}' -F $_.Major,$_.Minor}"')Do Set "OSVar=%%G"
```

If you really want to stick with using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) and `Get-CimInstance`:

```batch-file
For /F %%G In ('^""%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoP ^
 "(Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).Version.Split('.')[0,1] -Join '.'"^"'
) Do Set "OSVar=%%G"
```

As a oneliner:

```batch-file
For /F %%G In ('%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoP "(GCim Win32_OperatingSystem).Version.Split('.')[0,1] -Join '.'"')Do Set "OSVar=%%G"
```

However, should you prefer to parse it after retrieval in your `do` portion, then I'd suggest a simpler method than using tokens and delimiters:

```batch-file
For /F %%G In ('^""%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" ^
 -NoProfile -NoLogo "(Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).Version"^"'
) Do Set "OSVar=%%~nG"
```

As a oneliner:

```batch-file
For /F %%G In ('%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoP "(GCim Win32_OperatingSystem).Version"')Do Set "OSVar=%%~nG"
```

In the previous two examples the `.BuildNumber` is seen as an extension, so using metavariable expansion we can return the name without extension.

---

However, you don't need [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) to get the WMI information, you could use [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic) instead:

```batch-file
For /F %%G In ('"%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe" OS Get Version'
) Do If "%%~xG" NEq "" Set "OSVar=%%~nG"
```

And again as a oneliner:

```batch-file
For /F %%G In ('%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe OS Get Version')Do If "%%~xG" NEq "" Set "OSVar=%%~nG"
```

Comment: The problem with OSVersion is that it is deprecated in Windows 8 and can produce inconsistent results. I have seen Windows 8.1 (6.3.9600) identify itself as Windows 8 (6.2.9200). Using CIMInstance invokes WinRM which is the recommended method for querying this.

Comment: As far as I remember @JeremyBrown, the method which it used in the background was deprecated, but the command still works exactly as intended. Please try it, I know it works in Windows 10 at least!

Comment: It works, on the single computer I tried it on, but I have seen it produce the error I described on another machine. Microsoft Scripting Guy Ed Wilson seems to be under the same impression about Windows 8 and OSVersion: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-find-operating-system-version/

Comment: @JeremyBrown, deprecated means that in future versions it may be removed or no longer be supported. As I know it works in Windows 10, and you've seen it working in 8.1, you've kind of proven my point. However, if you're not satisfied with using anything other that `Get-CimInstance`, then I'd suggest you take a look at my edited answer, to see how I'd do it using that.

Comment: Well, you're kind of saying "It worked on 1 computer, therefor it will always work", when I showed demonstration that OSVersion has limitations on Windows 8. When you're rolling out a script for production to thousands of machines, you can't take a "good enough" approach.

Comment: No, I'm not saying it will always work, hence the reason why I included a simpler version using your specific command! You could also forget about using [tag:powershell], and use [tag:wmic] instead, so I've included that method in my answer too.

Comment: Thank you for the WMIC example, that example does work and shouldn't be problematic. It is also more version agnostic than CIMInstance.

Comment: If I was pedantic, @JeremyBrown,I  would suggest that my opening answer was about retrieving the required output from [tag:powershell], not retrieving the version using OSVersion. I am pedantic, so just to appease, I've added yet another version directly under the opening one, which doesn't use OSVersion, but still returns the string you want instead of parsing it afterwards.

Comment: I thank you for your diligence! I'm not sure that a command with 3 escapes qualifies as "simpler", but different people think in different ways. I find delims to be easier to work with.

Comment: That's correct, the simpler way is not to leverage [tag:powershell] at all, which is why I provided the [tag:wmic] option. However, my point was, if you want to leverage PowerShell within a `For` command, as it's generally accepted to be a more advanced tool, you may as well use that tool to return the required string, rather than performing an action on the string afterwards. In your case, the speed difference not worth discussing, but often can be. As for simpler, those escapes are only used to keep manageable line lengths in my code, I have now added the one liner of them to my answer too!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this what you want to extract :

```bat
@echo off
@For /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=." %%a in (
    '"powershell (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).version"'
) Do ( 
    Set "FirstVar=%%a"
    Set "SecondVar=%%b"
    Set "ThirdVar=%%c"
    Set "AllVar=%%a.%%b.%%c
)

echo FirstVar  = %FirstVar%
echo SecondVar = %SecondVar%
echo ThirdVar  = %ThirdVar%
echo AllVar    = %AllVar%
pause
```

Comment: This results in output of:

%a.%b


Setting tokens and delims on this seems to be tricky, possibly because it is piping the output of a powershell command that already has parentheses?

Comment: Add `UsebackQ` to the for loop options and change the single quotes to backticks.

Comment: TY both for the suggestions so far. I've tried this:  
```for /f "Tokens=1,2,3 delims=. USEBACKQ" %%a in (`"powershell (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).version"`) do (set "OSvar1=%%a" set "OSvar2=%%b" set "OSvar3=%%c" set "OSvar=%%a.%%b.%%c")
echo %OSvar%```  

And it results in this:  
```%a.%b```  

Even doing an ```echo %%a``` results in ```%a```

Comment: "USEBACKQ Tokens=1,2,3 delims=."

Comment: @T3RR0R, there is absolutely no reason to `usebackq` here.